# Sensu check for jvm heap not working

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jvm, sensu

I am facing issues with sensu-plugins-java. I have installed plugin in our server and I need to use check-java-heap-pcnt.rb to monitor the heap size in our server, but it is not showing proper output when I try to run the check locally. 
Here's how I tried to run the check locally:

```
# ./check-java-heap-pcnt.rb -n java -w 70 -c 85 -j /usr/java/defaults/bin/ -p
```

Here's the output it generated:

```
    invalid argument count
Usage: jstat -help|-options
       jstat -<option> [-t] [-h<lines>] <vmid> [<interval> [<count>]]

Definitions:
  <option>      An option reported by the -options option
  <vmid>        Virtual Machine Identifier. A vmid takes the following form:
                     <lvmid>[@<hostname>[:<port>]]
                Where <lvmid> is the local vm identifier for the target
                Java virtual machine, typically a process id; <hostname>is
                the name of the host running the target Java virtual machine;
                and <port> is the port number for the rmiregistry on the
                target host. See the jvmstat documentation for a more complete
                description of the Virtual Machine Identifier.
  <lines>       Number of samples between header lines.
  <interval>    Sampling interval. The following forms are allowed:
                    <n>["ms"|"s"]
                Where <n> is an integer and the suffix specifies the units as 
                milliseconds("ms") or seconds("s"). The default units are "ms".
  <count>       Number of samples to take before terminating.
  -J<flag>      Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system. 
(standard_in) 1: syntax error 
MEM UNKNOWN -
```

Comment: what version of jstat do you have installed?

Comment: @Frap Thanks for the reply. By jstat version do you mean the the java version? If that's the case then my current java version varies from  1.8.0_25 to 1.8.0_111.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the nagios plugins from 
https://kb.op5.com/display/HOWTOs/Jboss+Monitoring+with+check_jmx

and use with sensu.

Name:- check_jmx

For thread cound command:-

./check_jmx -U service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://'servername':'port'/jmxrmi -O java.lang:type=Threading -A ThreadCount  -K 9200 -w 250 -c 300

For Heap Memory:-

./check_jmx -U service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://'servername':'port'/jmxrmi -O java.lang:type=Memory -A HeapMemoryUsage -K used -I HeapMemoryUsage -J used -vvvv -w 102400 -c 81290